# Create custom XMLSerializer with all nodes in lower case

Tags: .net, xml

I am using XmlSerializer to generate XML output for my class. Is it possible to create a custom XMLSerializer that have all the xml nodes in lower case? I do not want to add attributes to every field field from my class to specify the node in lower case.

Thank you,
Angela

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends how much work you want to do. Adding attributes is the easiest option, but you say you don't want to do that. You could name the classes with lower-case names, but that is a horrible way of approaching this, IMO.

You *can* tell `XmlSerializer` what to do at runtime, by using `XmlAttributeOverrides` - but then you need to use reflection to tell it about all the members you want to tweak, but note: if you do this, you **must** cache and re-use such a serializer; if you create a new `XmlSerializer` via `XmlAttributeOverrides` every time, you will leak assemblies memory.

There's an example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides.aspx)

Comment: I did not think at the performance problem. I think I will use attributes for the time being.

Comment: @Marc, I think at the end of the day, you would need to do something at the `XmlTextReader` and `XmlWriter` level, since the `XmlSerializer` relies on these to do the actual work. Otherwise, as you mentioned, you'd have to mangle your class names to match the XML output.

Comment: @Marc, yeah, that's true. But doesn't give you the full control that you might need sometimes...

Comment: @Marc Seems the memory leak continues to be a problem into .Net 4. Anyone know if this has been fixed on later iterations.

Comment: @RichardDorman the perceived "memory leak" here is entirely down to incorrect usage; the expected usage in this scenario is that you *cache and reuse* the serializer - then: no problem

Answer (score 2):

The best example I've seen over the years is found [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/cazzu/archive/2004/05/10/129106.aspx), written by Daniel Cazzulino. I find it extremely elegant because he overrides the `XmlTextReader` and `XmlWriter` to make the serialization do **exactly** what he wants it to do. Hope you enjoy reading his blog!